# Posting form to different controller action not working in MVC

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have defined the default route in the **RouteConfig.cs** which show below:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "BackEnd", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

**BackEnd Controllers:**

```
public class BackEndController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Account Controller:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        public ActionResult LoginForm(Login item)
        {
            //Some code goes here...
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Login Partial:

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("LoginForm", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { placeholder = "Username" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    }
```

My form is not submitting to the controller action `Account/Login`.

Comment: Your route definition needs to be `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't want to define controller on url is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Then how do you expect to distinguish one controller from another?

Answer (score 0):

Then you are going to have to add another route to handler that url. This however defeats the purpose of convention-based routing.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "Login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "LoginForm" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "BackEnd", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```